# Having trouble with sorting

Tags: java, string, sorting, insertion-sort

So I am having a problem sorting an ArrayList. I am required to use in the insertion method so I am writing this code based off of that. What this is intended to do is the user is required to input 4 3-letter words and then they sorted in the ArrayList in alphabetical order. I have been trying different things but when I run the code it sorts the first word but repeats it. The output really depends on the words I put. I feel like my problem is in the while loop but I have been trying different ways but I am having the same problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import TerminalIO.KeyboardReader;

public class Insert{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,j;
        String tmp;
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        int run = 4;
        KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
        while(run!=0) {
            words.add(reader.readLine("Enter a three letter word: "));
            run--;
        }


        for (j=1; j<words.size(); j++) {
            i = j - 1;
            tmp = words.get(j);

            while ( (i>=0) && (tmp.compareTo(words.get(i)) < 0)){
                words.set(i,tmp); 
                words.set(i+1,words.get(i));
                i--;
            }

       //words.set(i+1,tmp);

        }

        for(int r = 0; r<words.size(); r++)
            System.out.print(words.get(r) + " ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to implement your own sort or just required to sort? If you simply want a sort try Collections.sort(words). Will sort alphabetically.

Comment: I think he's a student; students should do things by hand at least once.

Comment: Yes I am a student, the Collection.sort concept is not good for me because I am trying to learn how to modifying the insertion method to sort the strings.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you end up with duplicated words is the `while` block:

```
while ( (i>=0) && (tmp.compareTo(words.get(i)) < 0)){
    words.set(i,tmp); 
    words.set(i+1,words.get(i));
    i--;
}
```

You set the `i`-th word to `tmp`, and then you set the `i+1`-th word to the `i`-th word, which is `tmp`.

I'm afraid you have some code organization problems too.  First, please try to actually create an Insert object and then to call methods on that.  Make your methods smaller; each method should do just one thing.

Comment: I am probably having problems organizing the code. When you say I set the i+1 word to the i word, tmp is words.get(j) which makes it a different index. I am just confused on how to get this to sort in the correct way.

Comment: When I run that part of the code isn't it switching the word chosen from the j index one index behind it because i = j-1. After I do that I put the word that was compared and was located behind j into j's spot and this is done as the long as the while loop is correct

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. I removed words.set(i,tmp); from the while loop and in the for loop the code that I left commented I replaced it with words.set(i+1,tmp) and now it works. Thanks for the support though.

Comment: It's often useful to try simulating a computer on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `Collections.sort` instead of sorting yourself.  That would look like this after your while loop:

```
 while(run!=0){
   words.add(reader.readLine("Enter a three letter word: "));
   run--;
 }
 Collections.sort(words);
```

Comment: That does seem like a good idea but we need to understand how the insertion method works. There a few methods like the insertion method and the bubble method and we need to make it using the insertion method specifically.

Answer (score 0):

[`java.util.Collections.sort(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) will sort the array in the natural ordering of its elements as long as the elements implent the [Compareable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it this particular way, you need to use a String variable in the second while loop, let's call it tmp2:

```
   while ( (i>=0) && (tmp.compareTo(words.get(i)) < 0)){
   tmp2 = words.get(i);
        words.set(i,tmp); 
        words.set(i+1,tmp2);
       i--;
    }
```